# Svelte + Tailwind weird scroll behavior

Tags: hyperlink, tailwind-css, href, svelte

I'm working on a restaurant menu proyect using svelte + tailwind, as i'm finishing with details adding some scroll margin so the target id is not behind the sticky nav. I noticed a weird behavior on the links in the hamburger menu, first the scroll-m-8 (scroll-margin: 32px;) does not work at all, and second the links sometimes do not go to their respective id. tried all settings in data-sveltekit-preload both data and code thinking it was a preload behavior and also a few js workaround without being succesfull, can someone see what i'm missing? Thank you in advance. Here's the repo for the page https://github.com/ErnuB/mimocorito here is where i think the problem may be here

```
<script>
import { fly } from "svelte/transition";
export let open = false
function closeMenu() {
      open = false;
    };

    let section = [
        {img:"/img/brush-blue.png", id:'item1', name:"Item1"},
        {img:"/img/brush-pink.png", id:'item2', name:"Item2"},
        {img:"/img/brush-red.png", id:'item3', name:"Item3"},
        {img:"/img/brush-green.png", id:'item4', name:"Item4"},
        {img:"/img/brush-yellow.png", id:'item5', name:"Item5"},
    ];
</script>
  <nav class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center bg-yellow-400" transition:fly={{ y: -200, duration: 400}}>
    {#each section as sectionItem}
    <div class="relative my-4">
      <a href="#{sectionItem.id}" on:click={closeMenu} class="m-4 relative text-lg z-30 font-mocorito font-semibold">{sectionItem.name}</a>
      <img src="{sectionItem.img}" alt="Brush" class="absolute top-0 z-20 h-10 w-full pointer-events-none">
    </div>
    {/each}
  </nav>
```